# Strange error in Sqlite

Tags: android, transactions, android-sqlite, database-locking

In my problem case I am using a service to update a Database at a particular time every day, to increase the speed of insertions I have put the DB insertion operation inside a try-catch-finally block and used transactions, which I set successful in finally and end them there too. It all works flawlass on certain phones but crumbles on the Samsung Duos with Dual core and 4.0 jellybean. The error message I get is:

```
02-15 00:00:28.435: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(11250): The connection pool for database '+data+data+com_exa_xxx+databases+Bdr' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 1 (main) with flags 0x5 for 28.005001 seconds.
02-15 00:00:28.435: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(11250): Connections: 0 active, 1 idle, 0 available.
```

#### As such my application does not crash, but the service takes forever to complete. This is not the case with other phones.

Here is the complete code of my insert function:

```
public void refreshRecords(){
    dbHelper.beginTransaction();



    try{
        System.out.println("in refresh");
        int years; 
        long secon; 
        long min; 
        int hours;
        int mon; 
        int days;
        int weeks;
        String CONTACT_ID,CONTACT_NAME,CONTACT_IMAGE_URI; 
        String dateToInsert;

        intCal = new IntervalCalculation();


        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, h:mm a");
        String datex = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        SharedPreferences prefsx = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Editor editorx = prefsx.edit();
        editorx.putString("refresh", datex);
        editorx.commit(); 

        Cursor c = dbHelper.fetchAdhoc(); 
        dbHelper.NotificationDrop(); 


        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                try{
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
                    String displayBirthday = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DOB"));
                    String imageData = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ImageData"));
                    //CONTACT_ID,CONTACT_NAME,CONTACT_IMAGE_URI

                    CONTACT_ID = "10203040506070";
                    CONTACT_NAME = toTitleCase(name); 
                    CONTACT_IMAGE_URI = imageData; 
                    dateToInsert = displayBirthday; 

                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date date = format.parse(dateToInsert);
                    java.sql.Date dx = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
                    Date key = dx;

                    years = getDiffYear(key);               // For years elapsed
                    secon = seconds(key);                   // for seconds elapsed
                    min = seconds(key) / 60;                // For minutes elapsed
                    hours = (int) (seconds(key) / 60) / 60; // For hours elapsed
                    mon = months(String.valueOf(key));      // for months elapsed

                    days = daysElapsed(key);                // Days elapsed
                    weeks = daysElapsed(key) / 7;           // For weeks

                    dbHelper.insert(dateToInsert, CONTACT_NAME, String.valueOf(days), String.valueOf(hours), CONTACT_IMAGE_URI, String.valueOf(min),String.valueOf(mon), String.valueOf(secon), CONTACT_ID, String.valueOf(weeks), String.valueOf(years));

                    int PRIMARY_ID = dbHelper.getPrimaryId(); // Fetch the PrimaryId (_id) of the above inserted row, its the Foreign key for Notification and SpecialNotifications Table. 
                    String FOREIGN_KEY = dbHelper.getHighestID(PRIMARY_ID); // Same as above, but fetches the Name field of the last inserted row. 



                    //=========================================================================
                    //**Database Insertions Notifications Table/ SpecialNotifications Table**
                    //=========================================================================



                    //=======================================================================================//
                    //Regular intervals DB Insertions: 
                    //======================================================================================//
                    //Notification Types:
                    //1 for months
                    //2 for weeks
                    //3 for days
                    //4 for minutes
                    //5 for years
                    //6 for seconds
                    //7 for hours
                    //======================================================================================//

                    //==============================
                    //For Months 
                    //==============================
                    intCal.monthsNotify(mon, dateToInsert);
                    int monSpecial =  intCal.getMonthRegular(); 
                    Date dateMonReg = intCal.getMonRegDate(); 


                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(1, convertDate(dateMonReg), 0, monSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //===============================
                    //For Weeks 
                    //===============================
                    intCal.weeksToNotify(weeks,dateToInsert); 
                    int weekSpecial = intCal.getWeekRegular();
                    Date dateWeekReg =intCal.getWeekRegDate(); 

                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(2, convertDate(dateWeekReg), 0, weekSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);
                    //===============================
                    //For Days                      
                    //===============================
                    intCal.daysToNotify(days, dateToInsert); 
                    int daysSpecial= intCal.getDaysRegular();  
                    Date dateDaysReg = intCal.getDaysRegDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(3, convertDate(dateDaysReg), 0, daysSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);
                    //===============================
                    //For minutes
                    //===============================
                    intCal.minutesToNotify(min,dateToInsert);
                    long minutesSpecial= intCal.getMinutesRegular();
                    Date dateMinsReg = intCal.getMinutesRegDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(4, convertDate(dateMinsReg), 0,(int) minutesSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //==============================
                    //For Years
                    //==============================
                    intCal.yearsToNotify(years, dateToInsert); 
                    int yearsSpecial = intCal.getYearsRegular();
                    Date dateYearsReg = intCal.getYearsRegDate();
                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(5, convertDate(dateYearsReg), 0, yearsSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //=============================
                    //For Seconds
                    //=============================
                    intCal.secondsToNotify(secon, dateToInsert);
                    long secondsSpecial= intCal.getSecondsRegular(); 
                    Date dateSecondsReg = intCal.getSecondsRegDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(6, convertDate(dateSecondsReg), 0, secondsSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //=============================
                    //For Hours
                    //=============================
                    intCal.hoursToNotify(hours, dateToInsert); 
                    int hoursSpecial= intCal.getHoursRegular();
                    Date dateHoursReg= intCal.getHoursRegDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(7, convertDate(dateHoursReg), 0, hoursSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);



                    //============================================================================================//
                    //Special Intervals
                    //============================================================================================//
                    //Notification Types:
                    //1 for months
                    //2 for weeks
                    //3 for days
                    //4 for minutes
                    //5 for years
                    //6 for seconds
                    //7 for hours
                    //For Years
                    intCal.specialIntervalYears(years, dateToInsert); 
                    int yearsOnceSpecial =intCal.getYearsSpecial();
                    Date dateYearsSpecial = intCal.getYearsSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(5, convertDate(dateYearsSpecial), yearsOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //For Months
                    intCal.specialIntervalMonths(mon,dateToInsert); 
                    int monthsOnceSpecial= intCal.getMonthsSpecial();
                    Date dateMonthsSpecial = intCal.getMonthsSpDate();
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(1, convertDate(dateMonthsSpecial), monthsOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //For Weeks
                    intCal.specialIntervalsWeeks(weeks,dateToInsert); 
                    int weeksOnceSpecial= intCal.getWeeksSpecial(); 
                    Date dateWeeksSpecial = intCal.getWeeksSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(2, convertDate(dateWeeksSpecial), weeksOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);

                    //For Days
                    intCal.specialIntervalsDays(days, dateToInsert); 
                    int daysOnceSpecial= intCal.getDaysSpecial(); 
                    Date dateDaysSpecial = intCal.getDaysSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(3, convertDate(dateDaysSpecial), daysOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);

                    //For Hours
                    intCal.specialIntervalsHours(hours,dateToInsert); 
                    int hoursOnceSpecial= intCal.getHoursSpecial();  
                    Date dateHoursSpecial = intCal.getHoursSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(7, convertDate(dateHoursSpecial), hoursOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);

                    //For Minutes
                    intCal.specialIntervalMinutes(min,dateToInsert); 
                    long minutesOnceSpecial= intCal.getMinutesSpecial(); 
                    Date dateMinutesSpecial= intCal.getMinutesSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(4, convertDate(dateMinutesSpecial), (int)minutesOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);

                    //For Seconds
                    intCal.specialIntervalsSeconds(secon,dateToInsert); 
                    long secondsOnceSpecial= intCal.getSecondsSpecial(); 
                    Date dateSecondsSpecial= intCal.getSecondsSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(6, convertDate(dateSecondsSpecial), secondsOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID); 
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
            }while(c.moveToNext()); 
        }

        File toRead = null;
        try{
            File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/BirthdayReminders/output.txt");
            if (file.exists()) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/BirthdayReminders/output.txt"));     
                if (br.readLine() != null) {
                    toRead=new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/BirthdayReminders/output.txt");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("F1");
                    toRead=new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/BirthdayReminders/fileone.txt");
                }
            }else{
                toRead=new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/BirthdayReminders/fileone.txt");
            }

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(toRead);
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);
            String currentLine;
            int count = 0;

            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                count++;
                currentLine=sc.nextLine();
                StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(currentLine,"=",false);
                CONTACT_NAME = toTitleCase(st.nextToken());
                if(CONTACT_NAME.contains("'")){
                    CONTACT_NAME = CONTACT_NAME.replace("'", "");
                }
                System.out.println(CONTACT_NAME);
                // *********
                String listStr = st.nextToken();
                String cut = listStr.substring(1, listStr.length() - 1);
                String[] array = cut.split(",");
                CONTACT_ID = (array[0].trim());
                System.out.println(CONTACT_ID);
                String dateStr = (array[1].trim());
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
                java.sql.Date dx = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
                Date key = dx;
                dateToInsert = String.valueOf(dx); 

                CONTACT_IMAGE_URI = (array[2].trim());
                System.out.println(CONTACT_IMAGE_URI);

                years = getDiffYear(key);               // For years elapsed
                System.out.println(years);

                secon = seconds(key);                   // for seconds elapsed
                System.out.println(secon);
                min = seconds(key) / 60;                // For minutes elapsed
                System.out.println(min);
                hours = (int) (seconds(key) / 60) / 60; // For hours elapsed
                System.out.println(hours);
                mon = months(String.valueOf(key));      // for months elapsed
                System.out.println(mon);
                days = daysElapsed(key);                // Days elapsed
                System.out.println(days);
                weeks = daysElapsed(key) / 7;           // For weeks
                System.out.println(weeks);
                //dbHelper.open();
                //===============================================================================================================
                if (dateToInsert.contains("0001-") == true){ //Special Case, we added 0001 to Birthdays Which Have NO Year field. 
                    //===========================================================================================================

                    dbHelper.insert(dateToInsert, CONTACT_NAME, "","", CONTACT_IMAGE_URI, "", "", "", CONTACT_ID, "", ""); // All other fields will be empty, because we don't have a Year. 
                    int PRIMARY_ID = dbHelper.getPrimaryId();
                    String FOREIGN_KEY = dbHelper.getHighestID(PRIMARY_ID); 


                    //=====================================================================================================
                    //In this case we are only interested in fetching the year alert for next birthday of this contact -->
                    //=====================================================================================================

                    intCal.yearsToNotify(years, dateToInsert); 
                    int yearsSpecial = intCal.getYearsRegular();
                    Date dateYearsReg = intCal.getYearsRegDate();

                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(5, convertDate(dateYearsReg), 0, yearsSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID); 

                }
                //=========================================================================
                //Case when all the Date fields exist and we set up notifications  --->
                //=========================================================================
                else if(dateToInsert != "null" && dateToInsert.contains("0001-") != true){

                    dbHelper.insert(dateToInsert, CONTACT_NAME, String.valueOf(days), String.valueOf(hours), CONTACT_IMAGE_URI, String.valueOf(min),String.valueOf(mon), String.valueOf(secon), CONTACT_ID, String.valueOf(weeks), String.valueOf(years));

                    int PRIMARY_ID = dbHelper.getPrimaryId(); // Fetch the PrimaryId (_id) of the above inserted row, its the Foreign key for Notification and SpecialNotifications Table. 
                    String FOREIGN_KEY = dbHelper.getHighestID(PRIMARY_ID); // Same as above, but fetches the Name field of the last inserted row. 



                    //=========================================================================
                    //**Database Insertions Notifications Table/ SpecialNotifications Table**
                    //=========================================================================



                    //=======================================================================================//
                    //Regular intervals DB Insertions: 
                    //======================================================================================//
                    //Notification Types:
                    //1 for months
                    //2 for weeks
                    //3 for days
                    //4 for minutes
                    //5 for years
                    //6 for seconds
                    //7 for hours
                    //======================================================================================//

                    //==============================
                    //For Months 
                    //==============================
                    intCal.monthsNotify(mon, dateToInsert);
                    int monSpecial =  intCal.getMonthRegular(); 
                    Date dateMonReg = intCal.getMonRegDate(); 


                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(1, convertDate(dateMonReg), 0, monSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //===============================
                    //For Weeks 
                    //===============================
                    intCal.weeksToNotify(weeks,dateToInsert); 
                    int weekSpecial = intCal.getWeekRegular();
                    Date dateWeekReg =intCal.getWeekRegDate(); 

                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(2, convertDate(dateWeekReg), 0, weekSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //===============================
                    //For Days
                    //===============================
                    intCal.daysToNotify(days, dateToInsert); 
                    int daysSpecial= intCal.getDaysRegular();  
                    Date dateDaysReg = intCal.getDaysRegDate(); 

                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(3, convertDate(dateDaysReg), 0, daysSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //===============================
                    //For minutes
                    //===============================
                    intCal.minutesToNotify(min,dateToInsert);
                    long minutesSpecial= intCal.getMinutesRegular();
                    Date dateMinsReg = intCal.getMinutesRegDate(); 

                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(4, convertDate(dateMinsReg), 0,(int) minutesSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //==============================
                    //For Years
                    //==============================
                    intCal.yearsToNotify(years, dateToInsert); 
                    int yearsSpecial = intCal.getYearsRegular();
                    Date dateYearsReg = intCal.getYearsRegDate();

                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(5, convertDate(dateYearsReg), 0, yearsSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //=============================
                    //For Seconds
                    //=============================
                    intCal.secondsToNotify(secon, dateToInsert);
                    long secondsSpecial= intCal.getSecondsRegular(); 
                    Date dateSecondsReg = intCal.getSecondsRegDate(); 

                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(6, convertDate(dateSecondsReg), 0, secondsSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //=============================
                    //For Hours
                    //=============================
                    intCal.hoursToNotify(hours, dateToInsert); 
                    int hoursSpecial= intCal.getHoursRegular();
                    Date dateHoursReg= intCal.getHoursRegDate(); 

                    dbHelper.insertNotifications(7, convertDate(dateHoursReg), 0, hoursSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);



                    //============================================================================================//
                    //Special Intervals
                    //===========================================================================================//
                    //Notification Types:
                    //1 for months
                    //2 for weeks
                    //3 for days
                    //4 for minutes
                    //5 for years
                    //6 for seconds
                    //7 for hours
                    //For Years
                    intCal.specialIntervalYears(years, dateToInsert); 
                    int yearsOnceSpecial =intCal.getYearsSpecial();
                    Date dateYearsSpecial = intCal.getYearsSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(5, convertDate(dateYearsSpecial), yearsOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //For Months
                    intCal.specialIntervalMonths(mon,dateToInsert); 
                    int monthsOnceSpecial= intCal.getMonthsSpecial();
                    Date dateMonthsSpecial = intCal.getMonthsSpDate();
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(1, convertDate(dateMonthsSpecial), monthsOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //For Weeks
                    intCal.specialIntervalsWeeks(weeks,dateToInsert); 
                    int weeksOnceSpecial= intCal.getWeeksSpecial(); 
                    Date dateWeeksSpecial = intCal.getWeeksSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(2, convertDate(dateWeeksSpecial), weeksOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);

                    //For Days
                    intCal.specialIntervalsDays(days, dateToInsert); 
                    int daysOnceSpecial= intCal.getDaysSpecial(); 
                    Date dateDaysSpecial = intCal.getDaysSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(3, convertDate(dateDaysSpecial), daysOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);

                    //For Hours
                    intCal.specialIntervalsHours(hours,dateToInsert); 
                    int hoursOnceSpecial= intCal.getHoursSpecial();  
                    Date dateHoursSpecial = intCal.getHoursSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(7, convertDate(dateHoursSpecial), hoursOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);

                    //For Minutes
                    intCal.specialIntervalMinutes(min,dateToInsert); 
                    long minutesOnceSpecial= intCal.getMinutesSpecial(); 
                    Date dateMinutesSpecial= intCal.getMinutesSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(4, convertDate(dateMinutesSpecial), (int)minutesOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID);


                    //For Seconds
                    intCal.specialIntervalsSeconds(secon,dateToInsert); 
                    long secondsOnceSpecial= intCal.getSecondsSpecial(); 
                    Date dateSecondsSpecial= intCal.getSecondsSpDate(); 
                    dbHelper.insertSpecialNotifications(6, convertDate(dateSecondsSpecial), secondsOnceSpecial,FOREIGN_KEY,PRIMARY_ID); 
                    System.out.println("Iterating Count: "+count);
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Final Count: "+count);
            LC.writeToSD();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Inner Catch in service"+e);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Catch in service"+e);
    }finally{
        dbHelper.setTransactionSuccessful();
        dbHelper.endTransaction();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

}
```

#### Note: I am calling the above method from an Async Task, which I start in my Service.

Comment: did you found any answer?...I m facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Check that you do not have a transaction in another piece of code that has not yet completed.  This is the most likely cause of this error.

Make sure that you have not initiated your AsyncTask more than once and the methods you are calling in your dbhelper correctly open and close any internal transactions.

Comment: I am afraid that should not be the case, I think Async Task is somehow making things complex. I am sure about no other thread access because this all code is running in a Background service. At the moment I tested it in all modes, when the app is in forefront, when the app is in background and when the app is not in memory.